# return file object from generator python

Tags: python, xml, replace, generator

I'm using the following to read a file and let me edit a line inside the file

```
haystack = open('myxml.xml') 

def needlefinder(file):
    for line in file:
        if 'MyTag' in line:
            line = line.replace('alt="1"','alt="0"')
            #print line

    needle = needlefinder(haystack)
    print needle
```

Im wondering how can I return the file as a string? I want to basically edit this line on the fly and return the whole edited document.

Comment: This isn't a `generator` (no `yield`).  Title and tag should be changed.

Comment: @hpaulj correct. and there is a indentation problem in the code, the 4 lines of the `needlefinder` function should be indented of 4 spaces for the code to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Just place all the lines in a `list` (of `string`), and return it at the end of your function, like that:

```
def needlefinder(file_):
    lines = list()
    for line in file_:
        if 'MyTag' in line:
            line = line.replace('alt="1"','alt="0"')
        lines.append(line)
    return lines

haystack = open('myxml.xml')
needle = needlefinder(haystack)
print needle
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking how to return anything as a string then add a str()

```
return(str())
```

Comment: In this specific question, what the OP wants to return is already a `string`, so no need to call the `str` on it.

Comment: Adding a str() to a string won't cause any errors and adding a if statement would be more processing than a str("String")

Comment: Yes, and that's why there is no need to add `str` nor `if` because we already know that the values are `string`. It's not because a code does not cause error that we should add it. It's simply because it's not necessary

Comment: If you know that there will be only strings then return it normally.